# Get client IPv4 in ASP.NET 5 MVC 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, network-programming, windows-server-2012-r2

I have an asp.net 5 mvc 6 application hosted on a windows 2012 server and I need to get the IPv4 of the client PC's that will be running the app through a browser. I tried using Request.UserHostAddress but for some reason I keep getting an error that it's not a part of HttpRequest. I'm on DNX version 4.5.1, Solution DNX SDK Version is set to "1.0.0-rc-1-update-1" in the project properties, I have "using System.Web" in the top, I'm not sure why it's not working. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, this is a coding help website.  Where's the code? :P

Comment: You really should upgrade to ASP.NET Core RC2.  Many things have changed since the DNX version and it seems like a waste of time troubleshooting something that can never be used going forward.

Comment: is there a way to upgrade without it affecting my program negatively in it's current state? I'm too far into the program to try and break it, it's honestly my first time doing a big .net project, so I would appreciate the guidance. Thank you!

Comment: @Luke I know how this website works :) my problem is that I don't know what code I need, and I figured the question was clear enough, I'm sorry if it's not, English isn't my first language.

Comment: I know that you don't know what code you need, else you wouldn't need to be asking a question on this website.  Ner ner.  What code do you have a the moment?

Comment: Well, right now I'm trying to use Request.UserHostAddress because from all the guides online it seems like what I need, but I can't use it in my code for some odd reason. I can, however, use IPAddress hostIp = HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress; but it's not getting me results. Null objects. I'm lost on why my Request class seems to be messed up.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the ip address in the action method of an MVC controller `Request.UserHostAddress` will work but from any other place you should try using `string ip = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;` instead.